# Linq to Excel and publish to godaddy issue

Tags: c#, publish, linq-to-excel

All works fine on my machine , but after publishing to godaddy, I got this error :

```
 [5/28/2014 3:54:41 AM ]: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. , System.Data ,   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbServicesWrapper.GetDataSource(OleDbConnectionString constr, DataSourceWrapper& datasrcWrapper)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
   at LinqToExcel.Query.ExcelUtilities.GetWorksheetNames(ExcelQueryArgs args)
   at LinqToExcel.Query.ExcelQueryExecutor.GetWorksheetName()
   at LinqToExcel.Query.ExcelQueryExecutor..ctor(ExcelQueryArgs args)
   at LinqToExcel.Query.ExcelQueryable`1..ctor(ExcelQueryArgs args)
   at LinqToExcel.ExcelQueryFactory.Worksheet(Int32 worksheetIndex)
   at ArabicEWorld.BusinessLayer.NounManager.processNounFile(String path)
   at ArabicEWorld.WebService.ArabicEWorldWebService.ProcessNounsFile() ,
```

Any idea how to make it work fine on the hosting server, also it's sharing host I mean I cannot setup any programs on it.

Comment: Error msg is very clear: "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine."

Comment: I know it's clear but am not sure what to do to solve it , am not asking about the meaning, am asking what can I do while I cannot setup any programs

Comment: Is it a shared hosting or VPS or Dedicated server?

Comment: it's godaddy shared hosting

Comment: Then I think its not possible. There are lots of limitations in godaddy server. They do not provide Office interops in shared hosting. you better contact godaddy support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using openxml SDK , a little bit slower but it do the task

Answer (score 1):

Like Krishanu Dey mentioned in the comments, you can't use LinqToExcel on GoDaddy's shared hosting because they won't let you install the required OleDb engine that LinqToExcel uses.

You'll want to look into getting a VPS to install the OleDeb engine.